# Portable Media Player How to Upload Files?

Tags: android, batch-file

I just started to write a bat file to sync my music and podcasts to my 2 phones over USB. I can successfully sync to one phone however my other phone doesn't appear to even have a drive letter. Its type is a "Portable Media Player" according to Windows and simply has its name as "P9000" (the phone model number).

Is there a way I can send files to this type of device with a bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some third party tool that allows you to access a device via Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) with the command line.  This is what Windows Explorer is doing, just making an MTP device appear to be a normal directory, allowing you to copy media files to the device and speaking MTP under the covers.

One such tool is [MTP Drive](http://www.mtpdrive.com/), it creates a virtual drive letter for MTP devices, so you should be able to copy to the device like you're expecting to.